# Oblique coordinate transformation for integral

Tags: integration

I need to show
$$I\equiv\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2+2xy\cos\theta)} \, dx \, dy=\frac{\theta}{2\sin\theta}.$$

And the hint given is to consider oblique $xy$-coordinate.

I kinda can see how answers comes out.
If I transform the coordinate system where integrand becomes $e^{((1-\cos\theta) x'^2+(1+\cos\theta) y'^2)}$ and the integral argument is from $0$ to $\theta,$ I would get the similar value. But I'm stuck on how to construct transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this via the Jacobian, but it's possible to transform more or less one variable at a time:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2+2xy\cos\theta)}dx\,dy&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-y^2\sin^2\theta}\left\{\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x+y\cos\theta)^2}dx\right\}dy\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-y^2\sin^2\theta}\left\{\int_{y\cos\theta}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du\right\}dy\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-v^2}\left\{\int_{v\cot\theta}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du\right\}\frac{dv}{\sin\theta}\\
&=\csc\theta\int_0^{\infty}\int_{v\cot\theta}^{\infty}e^{-u^2-v^2}dudv\\
&=\csc\theta\int_{0}^{\theta}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-r^2}r\,dr\,dphi\\
&=\csc\theta\int_{0}^{\theta}\left[-\frac12e^{-r^2}\right]_0^{\infty}d\phi\\
&=\frac12\csc\theta\int_{0}^{\theta}d\phi\\
&=\frac12\csc\theta\left(\theta\right)\end{align}$$
So first we transformed $u=x+y\cos\theta$, then $y=y\sin\theta$, and then we could go into polar coordinate $u=r\cos\phi$, $v=r\sin\phi$ and then we had elementary integrals.